# Swiping on a item in the listview should load another activity associated with that particular item swiped

Tags: android, swipe

The scenario is, an activity consists of well designed listview. If I swipe (only from left to right) on a particular item in the list it should load the activity associated with that item. I tried coding it and also searching it, but didn't found the perfect explanation for swiping on a item in the listview.

I'm looking for a clear and elaborated explanation.

Comment: Use library https://github.com/JohannBlake/ListViewOrderAndSwipe

Comment: Thank you :) But my case is on swiping on a item it should navigate to another activity associated with that item.

Comment: Yes there would be a call back on swipe of item and you can start an activity on that callback method

Comment: Can you please provide me an example..